# SyntaxError: function statement requires a name in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I am new to Backbone framework. I have written model and view in backbone. It is giving me the syntax error or as "SyntaxError: function statement requires a name - >initObj: function (height, width) {" while running.

Here is my backbone view code

```
selectTable = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
    var height= 50;
    var width= 56;
        if (true) {
          initObj(chartHeight);
        }
        initObj: function (height, width) {
        console.log("inside initObj");
        }
      var selector = this.$el.find("select.clg-selection");
      selector.html("<option>testtest</option>");
    }
});
```

Here i am just calling "initObj" function but it is giving me the syntax error. Can anyone plese tell me what mistake am i doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initObj` function is not defined inside `render`. `initObj` is defined as an object property, therefore it should be placed inside of an object:

```
selectTable = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        var height= 50;
        var width= 56;
        if (true) {
          this.initObj(chartHeight);
        }
        var selector = this.$el.find("select.clg-selection");
        selector.html("<option>testtest</option>");
    },
    initObj: function (height, width) {
        console.log("inside initObj");
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can define `initObj` like:

```
initObj = function (height, width) {
    console.log("inside initObj");
}
```

and leave it inside `render`, but the first is more Backbone-ish.

Comment: Thanks for you information. After i did the changes as above, i get "I get a "ReferenceError: initObj is not defined" - everything seems to be right. What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you still getting "ReferenceError: initObj is not defined"? Booth of the solutions should work. If won't create a jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes Akoskm, Second solution is working fine. Can you please tell me what is the advantage/difference between these two declaration? or what purposes should each of them be used?

Comment: I prefer the first solution because it gives your code a better structure, you can easily distinguish your functions from the rest of your logic. It also gives you modularity, for example if you have to use initObj in more functions - using the first solution - you have to define it only once. While in the second solution you have to define it every time you use it. You should definitely go for the first solution.